# Compute relative orientation given azimuth, pitch, and roll in android?

Tags: android, math, orientation

When I listen to orientation event in an android app, I get a SensorEvent, which contains 3 floats - azimuth, pitch, and roll in relation to the real-world's axis.

Now say I am building an app like labyrinth, but I don't want to force the user the be over the phone and hold the phone such that the xy plane is parallel to the ground.  Instead I want to be able to allow the user to hold the phone as they wish, laying down or, perhaps, sitting down and holding the phone at an angle.  In other words, I need to calibrate the phone in accordance with the user's preference.

How can I do that?

Also note that I believe that my answer has to do with `getRotationMatrix` and `getOrientation`, but I am not sure how!

Please help!  I've been stuck at this for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Labyrinth style app, you probably care more for the acceleration (gravity) vector than the axes orientation. This vector, in Phone coordinate system, is given by the combination of the three accelerometers measurements, rather than the rotation angles. Specifically, only the **x** and **y** readings should affect the ball's motion.

If you do actually need the orientation, then the 3 angular readings represent the 3 Euler angles. However, I suspect you probably don't really need the angles themselves, but rather the rotation matrix **R**, which is returned by the **getRotationMatrix()** API. Once you have this matrix, then it **is** basically the calibration that you are looking for. When you want to transform a vector in world coordinates to your device coordinates, you should multiply it by the *inverse* of this matrix (where in this special case, inv(**R**) = transpose(**R**).

So, following the example I found in the documentation, if you want to transform the world gravity vector *g* ([0 0 g]) to the device coordinates, multiply it by inv(**R**):

**g** = inv(**R**) * *g*

(note that this should give you the same result as reading the accelerometers)

Possible APIs to use here: **invertM()** and **multiplyMV()** methods of the matrix class.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the accelerometer and the orientation sensor?  And why would I need the accelerometer in my case when what I care about is the rotation of the phone? The game needs to react to the user tilting their phone not speeding up.  I am sure what you are saying is right, but I cant grasp it!

Comment: @Gallal - first, even I can be wrong (sometimes...) ;-). Now, I assume you are trying to implement a Labyrinth style game. In this game, it is the gravity vector components that govern the ball's motion. When you tilt the phone to some direction (no need to actually move it - "speed it up") then the gravity in device coordinates has some nonzero component in the x and y direction. These components are measured by the x and y accelerometers. The z motion is restricted by the game's board. The ball just can't move in the z direction.

Comment: I am at the point where I obtained R and I using getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic).  When this method is called and R for future reference (not inverted), the phone is positioned in a way that is the desired position (ie. when the user clicks ‘calibrate’).   From this point on, I constantly get SensorEvent(s) of type Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD.  What do I do with the new event?  @ysap, thanks a lot for your help.  Like I said, I’ve been stuck at this for days; I’m not really good with 'spacial' critical thinking!

Comment: @Gallal - If I understand your problem, then what you want to accomplish is a "reset" position of the device, to be the reference to further rotations. So, when the user clicks `Calibrate`, you store the resultant **R** matrix (call it **Ri**). Then, you need to "subtract" this matrix, representing the rotation from world coordinates to initial device orientation, from the further readings of your device during game-time. Basically, the rotation matrix **R**, from the current orientation (**Rc**) to the initial orientation (**Ri**) is `R = inv(Ri) * Rc`.

Comment: ...  In rotation matrix math, "addition" of rotation is multiplication of the rotation matrices. So, "subtraction" is the multiplication with the inverse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any android-specific APIs, but all you want to do is decrease the azimuth by a certain amount, right? So you move the "origin" from (0,0,0) to whatever they want. In pseudocode:

```
myGetRotationMatrix:
    return getRotationMatrix() - origin
```