# Calculate device orientation relative to a fixed one with angles in world coordinate system

Tags: android, matrix, orientation, libgdx

I want to use my phone as a wheel in an android game. To do so I have to save the current orientation of my phone and get the relative angels to this saved orientation in device coordinates.

[image]

For example if I rotate the device around the z axis (see image above) I want to get that angle in respekt to the orientation I saved before.

From libGDX I only get the **azimuth**, **pitch** and **roll** angles **relative to the world coordinate system** (if I understood [this](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/InputCompass) right):

[image]

Any idea how I can calculate those relative angles?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.digikey.com/us/en/techzone/sensors/resources/articles/using-an-accelerometer-for-inclination-sensing.html)

Answer (score 0):

**How to calculate relative orientation.**

1) You can convert them to quaternions using [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.html#setEulerAngles%28float,%20float,%20float%29).
2) Take conjugate of the quaternion of initial orientation using [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.html#conjugate%28%29).
3) Multiply both using [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.html#mul%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Quaternion%29).
4) You now have relative orientation in form of a quaternion. To use it, you may either want to convert it to axis angle form using [this](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.html#getAxisAngle%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3%29), or [transform](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.html#transform%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3%29) a vector by this orientation.

---

**See whether do you really need relative orientation.**

If you need a simple wheel, accelerometer might be enough. More on this here: [Compute relative orientation given azimuth, pitch, and roll in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340804/compute-relative-orientation-given-azimuth-pitch-and-roll-in-android?rq=1)

Hope this helps. Good luck.